# Isekai manga about a boy and other people being teleported to a wired world

Tags: story-identification, manga, powers, parallel-universe, isekai

Its about a boy in his teens that lives up on a mountain in Japan.  His dad is a scientist and can't go anywhere near the city unless it's necessary. He has a strange ability where if he goes near electricity, it will react to him and somehow stop working, hence why he's in the mountains.

He would get bullied by the people in his class and had no friends. One day when he was out, he and a bunch of people in a hospital (I think), get teleported to another world. Before this his dad was getting shot at (can't remember details here). In this other world electricity doesn't work so he is able to do things freely and somehow has the power to make big monster looking animals be scared of him. That's all I can remember.

Comment: Is it a "wired world" or a "weird world"?

Answer (score 1):

The one you're lookin should be **Arata Primal**

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think this might be the correct manga, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It would help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.